# Showing the results of a search (made through a 3rd party search provider) inside an article

Tags: plugins

I'd like to develop a plugin that allows me to insert a shortcode in one article [show_image_search key="Alghe Wakamè"] and which will show something similar to the image below.

[image]

Where can I start from? (even a link to other questions / article / WP documentation could be a valid starting point)

Comment: The shortcode part, no, the google part, probably? 3rd party services are off topic here, but maybe if you had an example of this in a static web page? Questions here are limited to WordPress, the Google API is out of scope here

Comment: Thanks, but I wouldn't use it.. for just a few dozen of searches I think it's not needed. It's ok to cache the search once every year.

Comment: +1 to @TomJNowell comment, consider migrating this to StackOverflow for a PHP function that will return markup for a Google Search, then refer back here for help with shortcode implementation.

Comment: Who is going to use this is somewhat irrelevant. 3rd party services ( such as Google ) are off topic on this site. I understand your question is reasonable, but parts of it are out of scope here, if we can remove those parts or factor them out then we can avoid closing the question and make your question more attractive to people answering

Comment: @TomJNowell: I will edit my question, but just because I love factual evidence.. Are you sure that "3rd party services are out of scope in this community"? Googling site:stackexchange.com "google" returns 1.490.000 results.. Not 1.. not 5.. not 10.. but 1 million.. What you expressed is an opinion but factual evidence are completely strongly opposite. ps: sorry if I've been aggressive and unfriendly. I had tons of bad experience with this community. I understand why you all do this, but I think flexibility should be more appreciated. What annoys me is the distortion of facts for looking right

Comment: [It's stated clearly as one of the reasons available for closing a question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is the WordPress stack exchange, and different stacks define what 'ontopic' means differently. E.g. a Physics question is off topic on a Biology stack exchange. However arguing in comments is not going to help, if you disagree we have processes for these things. Visit the Meta site and make your case, if you're persuasive, things will change

Comment: @TomJNowell: don't worry, I edited my question, I wanted just to point out that, off topic or not, this community spoke of google 1 million of times in his pages... This is not very coherent with the rules it has defined.

Comment: Different stack exchange sites have different rules, e.g. I expect Google would be mentioned a lot on the Webmasters stack exchange, what works in one stack isn't appropriate in another, and if someone says "I googled for the answer and found nothing", that doesn't meant he question is about Google, but it would show up in your google search query

Comment: I interpret the question as _"I would like to develop a plugin which uses an external service to embed content in posts via a shortcode. This is what I am attempting to accomplish... where should I start?"_ or, more succinctly, _I would like to write a plugin that provides a shortcode; how do I do this?_ In this context, rather than off-topic for pertaining to 3rd-party products, I actually think this is off-topic for being overly-broad (and inspiring opinion-based answers regarding "where to start"), or low quality for showing little to no research effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, your question boils down to *"How do I display third-party data via a shortcode?"* It's a frequent task that a large number of WordPress developers encounter at one time or another over the course of their career, and the solution is simple: combine the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) with [a mechanism that retrieves the 3rd-party data](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) and wrap it all up in [a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).

That's really all there is to it. If the 3rd-party data changes infrequently, you may wish to cache it with the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), or maybe just download it the first time and store it alongside relevant posts using the [Metadata API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Metadata_API) and store binary data as an [attachment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment).

It can be as simple and straightforward or complicated and efficient as you want it to be, and there are many ways to accomplish the same tasks. [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/) is always a good place to start, as is searching the web for relevant blog posts and tutorials.

We can help you out with any specific questions you have regarding the WordPress functions and structures and their use (there's likely already answers for most that you might ask here on the site), but for questions regarding obtaining data from a third-party service (or the specific application of PHP or Javascript towards doing so) you should inquire over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), or on the 3rd-party's official support channels.

To increase your chances of receiving constructive answers, conduct ample research before asking a question, phrase it in a manner that makes it clear you are addressing WordPress functionality specifically, and generalize it as much as possible to apply to the largest possible audience.